# Cannot buy/download anyting from iTunes store

Tags: itunes

I'm running iTunes 9.0.2.25.  I open iTunes store without any problem; however, when I try to buy or download anything I get a message box with following error:

> **Could not purchase "XXX".  The network**
>   **connection timed out.**
>
> Make sure your network settings are correct and your network
>   connection is active, then try again.

I tried to restart iTunes.  I even reboot my PC but so far no success.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:
1. Firewall/anti-spyware/anti-virus?
2. Are you running a proxy software (like Privoxy)?
3. Try re-installing iTunes.
4. Any other network issues?
5. Is iTunes available in the country you're at right now?

Comment: Thanks.  I tried to repair iTunes from Uninstall or changed program and it worked.  +1.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same problem.